# How to get inner and outer window dimensions with Xlib/XCB?

Tags: xlib, xorg, xserver, xcb

Is there a reliable way to get the inner and outer rectangle of a top
level window with XCB/Xlib? (IOW frame and client rectangle).

Here's what I tried:

- xcb_get_geometry always returns the initial dimensions even after
  the window gets resized (what gives?)
- I figured I would call xcb_query_tree repeatedly until I find the
  window's frame window - is this the way to do it? I figure ICCCM/EWMH
  should provide this but couldn't find anything. Is there any other
  standard/non-standard for this? Anyway that doesn't work with
  compiz/ubuntu10 because xcb_query_tree reports the client window as
  having root = parent (under normal ubuntu wm the window gets properly
  reparented).
- xcb_translate_coordinates() seemed to be the only reliable way to
  get root-based coords[1] in 2007 -- is this still the case? I.e. is
  XCB_CONFIGURE_NOTIFY non-standard with WMs?

[1] http://fixunix.com/xwindows/91652-finding-position-top-level-windows.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer as it only explains how to find the inner dimensions of a window. Also I am not sure if this is the canonical way to go but it works for me.

You can subscribe to the `XCB_EVENT_MASK_RESIZE_REDIRECT` event when creating a window:

```c
xcb_window_t           window    = xcb_generate_id          (connection);
const xcb_setup_t     *setup     = xcb_get_setup            (connection);
xcb_screen_t          *screen    = xcb_setup_roots_iterator (setup).data;
uint32_t               mask      = XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK;
uint32_t               valwin[1] = { XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE
                                   | XCB_EVENT_MASK_RESIZE_REDIRECT };

xcb_create_window(
    connection,
    XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
    window,
    screen->root,
    0, 0,
    800, 600,
    0,
    XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
    screen->root_visual,
    mask, valwin);
xcb_map_window(connection, window);
xcb_flush(connection);
```

In the event loop you can then keep track of resizes:

```c
xcb_generic_event_t *event;
uint16_t width = 0, height = 0;
while ((event = xcb_wait_for_event(connection)) != NULL) {
    switch (event->response_type & ~0x80) {
    case XCB_EXPOSE: {
        /* ... */
        break;
    }
    case XCB_RESIZE_REQUEST: {
        auto resize = (xcb_resize_request_event_t*) event;
        if (resize->width > 0) width = resize->width;
        if (resize->height > 0) height = resize->height;
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
    free(event);
    xcb_flush(connection);
}
```

Note that I am not sure whether this event is emitted when you initiate the resize from your application code using `xcb_configure_window` for example. I never tested it and just update the `width` and `height` in a wrapper function for `xcb_configure_window`.